# Laravel set option to selected if option id is in an array list in blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I made query in my controller and send it to my blade :

```
public function editContractorAssociation(DeveloperContractorAssociation $developer_contractor_association, Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $developer_contractor_association = DeveloperContractorAssociation::whereHas('defect_types', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
        })->orwhereHas('contractor', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
        })->first();
        return view('dev-admin.contractors.associations.edit', ['developer_contractor_association' => $developer_contractor_association]);
    }
```

and when I call `{{ $developer_contractor_association->defect_types }}` in my blade, I get this :

```
[
    {
        "id":2,
        "title":"Wiring",
        "details":"Fix wiring",
        "created_by":"22",
        "created_at":"2019-09-04 11:39:48",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-04 11:39:48",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "is_custom":1,
        "developer_id":1,
        "pivot":{"dca_id":87,"defect_type_id":2}},
        {"id":3,"title":"Plumbing",
            "details": "Fix Pipe",
            "created_by":"22",
            "created_at":"2019-09-04 11:40:07",
            "updated_at":"2019-09-04 11:40:07",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "is_custom":1,
            "developer_id":1,
        "pivot":{"dca_id":87,"defect_type_id":3}
    }
]
```

Now I have a select field that list all the defect type that existed :

```
<select class="selectpicker {{ $errors->has('defect-type-id') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="defect-type-id[]" id="defect-type-id" multiple data-style="selectpicker-style" data-width="100%" title="Defect Types">
    @foreach(App\DefectType::select('id','title')->get() as $defect_type)
        <option value="{{$defect_type->id}}">{{$defect_type->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

When population the option for the select field, How can I check if the `id` is in the `defect_type_id` JSON and set the option to selected. Something like this :

```
<select class="selectpicker {{ $errors->has('defect-type-id') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="defect-type-id[]" id="defect-type-id" multiple data-style="selectpicker-style" data-width="100%" title="Defect Types">
    @foreach(App\DefectType::select('id','title')->get() as $defect_type)
        {{if $defect_type->id in $defect_type_list}}
            <option value="{{$defect_type->id}}">{{$defect_type->title}} selected</option>
        {{else}}
        <option value="{{$defect_type->id}}">{{$defect_type->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I think you will get the instance of the `{{ $developer_contractor_association->defect_types }}` or `{{ $developer_contractor_association->contractor }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `defect_types` relationship returns a Laravel [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections), you can use a couple of the Collection methods:

```php
@foreach(App\DefectType::select('id','title')->get() as $defect_type)    
    <option value="{{$defect_type->id}}"
        @if($developer_contractor_association->defect_types->pluck('id')->contains($defect_type->id))
            selected
        @endif
    >
        {{$defect_type->title}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

[`pluck('id')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) returns a Collection of `defect_type` `id` and you can then check if the current iteration of all `defect_type` is in that Collection with [`contains($defect_type->id)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains).

You may use [`containsstrict()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-containsstrict) instead of `contains()` as that makes a strict comparison.